# Why is my Javascript test() function failing when I put a space bar in the regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have this:

```
var regex=/[a-z\d,]+$/i;

if (!/[a-z\d,]+$/i.test(user_input)){
      alert('format is invalid');
}
```

This works, but when I want to include the " " character (space) in the regex, the function fails or doesn't trigger the block inside the if statement.

```
var regex=/[a-z\d ,]+$/i;
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you defining the regex twice?

Comment: Hi. No I don't I just replace the first one by the second one and that's when it fails

Comment: `/[a-z\d ,]+$/i.test('A, b')` works fine for me.

Comment: [**@Rocket DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XEBRK/)

Comment: Hi there. By adding a "^" in the regex it solved the problem. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the start pattern `^`

```
/^[a-z\d ,]+$/i.test(user_input)
```

Otherwise you test only if you match at the end of the line.
Try here: [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5E%5Ba-z%5Cd%20,%5D%2b%24&input=123%20This%20is%20a%20Test)

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. Thanks a lot for your help. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is represented by `\s` :

```
 var regex=/[a-z\d\s,]+$/i;
```

Comment: You can use a literal space in a regex.  `\s` also includes tabs (and newlines, I think).

Comment: Rocket is right, `\s` includes the `\n`, `\r` and `\t` chars as well as white space.

Comment: @Rocket, that's right. I looked at the spec and it includes new lines.

Answer (score 1):

As told above, whitespace is represented by '\s'.

```
 var regex=/[a-z\d\s,]+$/i;
```

For more clarification, visit following url :
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/regularexpressionsyntax.htm

Comment: You can use a literal space in a regex.  `\s` also includes tabs (and newlines, I think).